# I decided to build my pygame project from .py format to exe. When i tried to run the script, i get an error

Tags: python, pygame, game-development

My project has a lot of files, this application starts with start.py script.
When i run this script, i get an "Import Error".
I using a pyinstaller module for build my project to exe.

Code

```
import json
import os

import pygame as pg

from about import About
from code import App


class Menu:
    def __init__(self):
        pg.init()
        pg.mixer.init()

        self.file_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        self.json_conf_dir = os.path.join(self.file_dir)
        self.font_dir = os.path.join(self.file_dir)
        self.img_dir = os.path.join(self.file_dir)

        with open(os.path.join(self.json_conf_dir, "file_paths.json")) as file_paths:
            self.data = json.load(file_paths)

        self.font_file = os.path.join(self.font_dir, self.data["fonts"][1])
        self.background_img = pg.image.load(os.path.join(self.img_dir, self.data["images"]["menu_imgs"]["background"]))
        self.logo_img = pg.image.load(os.path.join(self.img_dir, self.data["images"]["icon"]))

        self.height, self.width = 1000, 600
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((self.height, self.width))
        pg.display.set_caption("Battle on Tower {MENU}")
        pg.display.set_icon(self.logo_img)
        self.colors = [(0, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255), (255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255)]
        self.menu = True
        self.menu_cycle()

    def menu_cycle(self):
        while self.menu:
            for event in pg.event.get():
                if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                    self.menu = False
                self.button_press_event(event)
                self.update_screen()

    def text_render(self, text, font, size, color, x, y):
        font = pg.font.Font(font, size)
        text = font.render(text, True, color)
        self.screen.blit(text, (x, y))

    def draw_buttons(self):
        global play_btn, quit_btn, about_btn
        play_btn = pg.draw.rect(self.screen, self.colors[-2], (400, 200, 200, 75))
        quit_btn = pg.draw.rect(self.screen, self.colors[2], (400, 300, 200, 75))
        about_btn = pg.draw.rect(self.screen, self.colors[1], (400, 400, 200, 75))
        self.text_render("Play", self.font_file, 60, self.colors[0], 420, 210)
        self.text_render("Quit", self.font_file, 60, self.colors[0], 420, 310)
        self.text_render("About", self.font_file, 50, self.colors[0], 400, 420)
        pg.draw.rect(self.screen, self.colors[-1], (400, 200, 200, 75), 3)
        pg.draw.rect(self.screen, self.colors[-1], (400, 300, 200, 75), 3)
        pg.draw.rect(self.screen, self.colors[-1], (400, 400, 200, 75), 3)

    def button_press_event(self, event):
        global play_btn, quit_btn, about_btn
        if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            mouse_pos = pg.mouse.get_pos()
            if play_btn.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                App()
                self.menu = False
            if quit_btn.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                self.menu = False
            if about_btn.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                About()
                self.menu = False

    def update_screen(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.background_img, (0, 0))
        self.draw_buttons()
        pg.display.update()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    menu = Menu()
```

Class method, where are creating intances of classes from other scripts:

```
    def button_press_event(self, event):
    global play_btn, quit_btn, about_btn
    if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        mouse_pos = pg.mouse.get_pos()
        if play_btn.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            App()
            self.menu = False
        if quit_btn.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            self.menu = False
        if about_btn.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            About()
            self.menu = False
```

Photo of the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtusC.png)

[Link to my GitHub with full version of my project](https://github.com/coder6497/Battle-on-Tower)

pyinstaller command:

```
 pyinstaller --windowed --onefile --add-data "data;." --add-data "about.py;." --add-data "code.py;." --add-data "file_paths.json;." --icon=icon.ico menu.py
```

Comment: Please post errors as plain text in the question.  Image links just make it harder for us to help.

Comment: What you haven't showed us is your `pyinstaller` command and any config script.  What file did you tell it to use as the main file?  It should be able to find all the dependencies, but perhaps you configured it incorrectly.  Remember that `code` is the name of a standard Python module.  You might need to force `pyinstaller` to include yours, or use another name.

Comment: Thanks, building to exe is working and the .exe file runs succesfully

Answer (score -1):

It means that "App" is not a Part of "code" Could be wrong caps or name, Or you don't have a "code" library, or an issue with the code of the Library.

Comment: That's not really very helpful.  If he had any of those problems, it wouldn't run for him locally.  This is something specific to the pyinstaller build.